# ng-repeat shows diffent values during execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**[Problem]**

Ok, I have no idea of what is really going on here. But here is the thing: I'm showing a table with some information from users and there's a button that the user can click in order to show more information from that user. The approach I took to create this is for each user a form is created to send the information when the users hits the button "Check".

Everything sounds fine, but, there are random moments when I access the system the field 'ID' from the table (`<td>{{data.id}}</td>`) shows the value of the id correctly but the (`<input type="hidden" name="_user" value="{{data.id}}" />`) doesn't. They come from the same object, data.id, how come they could show different values?

The code for the table follows:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.city}}</td>
                <td>{{data.state}}</td>
                <td>{{data.country}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" name="check" value="Check" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="_user" value="{{data.id}}" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

If somebody helps me on this I'd really appreciate. I also would appreciate any comment related to the approach I've taken in order to send the data to the server. Thanks in advance.

**[How to reproduce]**

When I access the screen for showing the users from the main panel, the table above shows everything rendered fine and the hidden values are set correctly. Then if I click on "check", I'll see the user data in another screen and if I hit the back button from the browser, I'm able to see the table above rendered properly (the id field in the table is correct) but the hidden field get the value="0". All of them.

**[Solution]**

Using ng-value instead of value saved me! Thanks you all!

Comment: I find this extremely hard to believe, can you recreate a live example (here as a snippet or plunker or jsfiddle etc...)

Comment: When you say 'shows a different value', is it an entirely other id or is it null?

Comment: I tried to create some examples on fiddle but they work fine. I cant reproduce this error with external resources, cause they work properly. The thing is that this is happening randomly and it is driving me nuts. There are some other guys I asked to check with me but they couldn't figure out yet what's going on.

Comment: @JohnF. it shows <input type="hidden" name="_user" value="0" /> for every form from the table

Comment: Are you using some templating engine that uses double braces just like Angular does?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the support in the question. I know now how to reproduce it, but not how to solve. When I access the screen for showing the users from the main panel, the table above shows everything rendered fine and the hidden values are set correctly. Then if I click on "check", I'll see the user data in another screen and if I hit the back button from the browser, I'm able to see the table above rendered properly (the id field in the table is correct) but the hidden field get the value="0". All of them. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Shomz, no I'm not using.

Comment: You should probably switch to `ng-model="data.id"` then. It could be that Angular doesn't bother recheching the value of the input field when you go back because you should use ng-model on it.

Comment: I've tried '<input type="hidden" name="_user" value="{{data.id}}" ng-model="data.id"  />' and '<input type="hidden" name="_user" ng-model="data.id"  />' the seconde case showed the same error. The second one throw an error. The id wans't sent to server.

Comment: it's a error in the php query because the id wasnt send to the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following resource of angularJs, [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).